# Pass comma separated list as parameter in Oracle function

Tags: oracle, function

I'm trying to create a function to pass a list separated with commas as a parameter to the IN clause.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE FUNCTION "GET_EMPLOYEES_COUNT"(DEPT_STRING VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

count_emp VARCHAR2(10);

BEGIN

  select count(*) from employees where deptname IN (DEPT_STRING);

  RETURN count_emp;

END GET_EMPLOYEES_COUNT;
```

However, I am getting null when trying to call the following:

```
SELECT GET_EMPLOYEES_COUNT('''AGRICULTURE'',''IT''') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "GET_EMPLOYEES_COUNT"(DEPT_STRING VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

count_emp NUMBER;

BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[DECLARE q number;
          begin  select count(*) INTO q from employees
          where deptname IN ( ]' || DEPT_STRING || q'[);
          :x := q;end;]'
    USING OUT count_emp;

   RETURN count_emp;

END GET_EMPLOYEES_COUNT;
/
```

Live demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a1360/1

Comment: No. that will not work.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I've updated the answer, this time it is tested and worked.

Comment: This works, but doesn't use bind variables;)

Comment: `GET_EMPLOYEES_COUNT( '1) OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM passwords_table WHERE username = ''Alice'' AND hash = ''12345678''' )` is probably not the functionality you were intending to allow.

Comment: deptname is of type varchar2 actually. I'm trying to make it work here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4802b/1